# What is a one syllable word for "could not"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a poem and I need a word meaning **"could not"** that is only one syllable to be able to fit into the rhythm. **I need it to be in past tense also.**

I need it to replace "couldn't" in this line

> That **couldn’t** be quenched with water.

And the  whole stanza is

> She set fiercest fires I’ve ever seen,
>
> That **couldn’t** be quenched with water.
>
> Her talons raked the earth so deep,
>
> She crushed through bricks and mortar.

---

**EDIT:**

I can easily change the line to something else, but I won't do so unless there is no alternative to "Could not". So I would prefer if future answers would refrain from suggesting that I change the line or the words in it to replace "Could not".

Comment: Water and mortar rhyme? Is this for non-rhotic speech or people with epenthetic-r, who say 'warsh' for 'wash'?

Comment: Suggest: Don't use words such as "That" in lyrics.   Change the second line to simply "Can't be quenched with water".

Comment: Sorry, there is no one syllable word that means exactly the same thing (including tense) as "could not", So you're either going to have to rework the line a bit, per several suggestions, or be ok with two syllables.

Comment: Quite honesty, if you're around my neck of the woods, "couldn't" _is_ one syllable. Dictionary.com's first pronunciation guide is *[koo d-nt]* which is one actual vowel + what I would consider a "swallowed" vowel, and is not perceived as a full syllable.

Answer (score 8):

*Can't* is one syllable, means (roughly) "couldn't", and scans correctly in your poem.

Further, *can't* has nice alliteration with *quenched* and *crushed* in line 4.

Also, you might consider changing the first line to the following variant:

> She set the fiercest fires I've seen

This variant scans better (it's iambic tetrameter, like line 3), and turns the four lines into acceptable 8/7/8/7 meter.

Comment: I am looking for past tense verbs.

Comment: Fair enough. But given it's a relative clause, "can't" works fine without distorting the meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate line though, that helped a lot.

Comment: Another suggestion is to consider removing the 's' from 'bricks', rendering the phrase 'brick and mortar' (two mass nouns). I think the line sounds better without the sibilance (despite the fact that line 1 is highly sibilant). But that's probably highly subjective so do what you think is best.

Comment: IMO *shan't* would be a better choice, retaining the subjunctive mood.

Comment: @OrangeDog, is *shan't* subjunctive? Further, isn't *shan't* only for 1st person pronouns like *I* and *we*? I think that the alliteration and naturalness of *can't* beats anything *shan't* offers, but to each his/her own.

Comment: Perhaps technically not, but in this piece of poetry it is closer in its sense of uncertainty to *could* than *can*.

Comment: I hope you'll give @Silenus co-authorship.

Answer (score 5):

In poetry there's never a right answer, since you can break all kinds of rules that usually would hold you back.
Try changing the line to "unquenchable by water", or you could even extend 'couldn't' into 'could not' and drop 'That': "Could not be quenched with water".

It's your poem, so you must find the words that say it perfectly. Maybe these ideas will spark off something else? You don't need to limit yourself.

Comment: Even though the context is a poem, the request is for a single monosyllable which means the same as "could not." I don't think it's fair to say that there is no "right answer" just because it's poetry...

Answer (score 2):

I would take @Silenus's suggestion. But if you refuse that, you might rewrite the lines as:

> She set the fiercest fires I've seen,
>
> **Unquenchable with water.**
>
> Her talons raked the earth so deep,
>
> She crushed through bricks and mortar.

Comment: Good idea, but I think 'Unquenchable by water' is better.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like *can't*, how about **won't**? Poetry tends to mix timing and so the usual rules of tenses can be somewhat bent...

> She set the fiercest fires I’ve seen,
>
> That won’t be quenched with water.
>
> Her talons raked the earth so deep,
>
> She crushed through bricks and mortar.

Comment: I specifically mentioned past tense.

Comment: Damn, you're making this hard :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try *shan't*?

> shan't
>
> (Britain) **shall not**
>
> *I shan't dignify that with an answer. What a stupid question!*
>
> *Shall we go to see a film this afternoon? No we shan't.*

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I've never actually seen it used</strike>, but perhaps "coul'n't"? Contractions aren't limited to single elisions (see "fo'c'sle"), and it's not too much of a stretch to assume that removing the "d" could change the pronunciation from /ˈkʊd.(ə)nt/ to something like /ˈkʊnt/.

Update: OK, I didn't just make this up :)

From [*The Deerslayer* by James Fenimore Cooper](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/cooper-deerslayer-367.html):

> "Well, if it's agreeable, I should think a woman **coul'n't** hear it too often."

Answer (score 0):

> That **ne'er was**  quenched with water.

From http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ne-er:

> adverb, Literary. 1.**never**.
>     ...

Note: I've changed next word *be* -> *was* to get the past tense the OP desires.